# Power BI Dashboard Connected with S3 data is not working when Publish to Cloud

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, powerbi, aws-api-gateway, powerbi-desktop

I have some CSVs in AWS S3. Those are connected with a dashboard developed in Power BI desktop. The data is connected through "Simba Athena ODBC Driver".

Now, the problem is, when I am publishing that dashboard from Desktop to make that available into cloud at "https://app.powerbi.com/" it is giving error as

"There is no gateway to access the data source extension".

*How to configure the gateway for S3 Bucket data for Power BI*? Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The refreshing using the Athena driver [requires](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/power-bi-data-sources) a [gateway](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/gateway/).

Comment: Thank you for the tips. Can you elaborate a little bit, please? Any video or url or tutorial is there for this?

Actually when I am checking in the gateway link, it is showing the following:

Error code: DMTS_DatasourceHasNoCredentialError
Data source error: Datasource has no credentials
Cluster URI: https://api.powerbi.com
Activity Id: 2ca09f1f-c76d-4aca-a507-e848fd4e9718
Request Id: 337c9ab3-1773-4a97-97d8-92280d8c6f9b
Time: Tue Oct 25 2022 16:26:52 GMT+0300 (Eastern European Summer Time)

Comment: Here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/service-gateway-deployment-guidance and  https://youtu.be/Vlv1tbuZNcM

Comment: Hi David,

I tried that way but getting following error, Any advise?

Unable to create data source.
Unable to connect to the data source. Either the data source is inaccessible, a connection timeout occurred, or the data source credentials are invalid. Please verify the data source configuration and contact a data source administrator to troubleshoot this issue.

Trailing part is given below

Comment: Details:

OLM Gateway: ODBC: ERROR [HY000] [Simba][DriverSupport] (1030) Failed to decrypt data: Key not valid for use in specified state.
ERROR [HY000] [Simba][DriverSupport] (1030) Failed to decrypt data: Key not valid for use in specified state.

Please have this information handy if you choose to create a support ticket.

ActivityId: 682bc0ca-d718-46d7-84d4-ce234aaa4923
RequestId: df5816f6-8ef4-42a8-ac02-c56e391b138c
Cluster URI: https://api.powerbi.com
Status code: 400
Time: Wed Oct 26 2022 13:48:35 GMT+0300 (Eastern European Summer Time)